# Google Cloud Vision API using Cloud Shell: How can I run the API for multiple images? What should my request.json look like?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I've run a test on a single image [using Cloud Shell] and the request.json is like the below. How can I run the Vision API for an entire folder of images?
Also, why does the user permissions for images need to be public for the API to run?
Thanks.

```
{
"requests": [
      {
"image": {
"source": {
"gcsImageUri": "gs://visionapitest/landmark/test.jpeg"
          } 
        },
"features": [
          {
"type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
"maxResults": 10
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform the request by using the Cloud Shell, you have to do it in the following way

```
{
"requests": [
{
  "image": {
    "source": {
      "gcsImageUri": "gs://visionapitest/landmark/test.jpeg"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
      "maxResults": 10
    }
  ]
},
{
  "image": {
    "source": {
      "gcsImageUri": "gs://visionapitest/landmark/test2.jpeg"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
      "maxResults": 10
    }
  ]
}, … ]}
```

Please note, that isn’t a way to specify a complete folder, as you can see the “requests” field is an array of [AnnotateImageRequest](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageRequest) objects, so you have to itemize every image within the JSON file.

On the other hand,  you can dynamically create the “requests” array by using one of the available [Vision Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries) in order to read all the images within the folder. I would like to share a python code snippet I took from the [Vision API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#sample_code), although it only contemplated an image but I modified it to read the entire folder.

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import enums
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types
from re import search

def sample_async_batch_annotate_images(
   bucket_name,
   output_uri
):
"""Perform async batch image annotation."""
client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

storage_client = storage.Client()
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(
    bucket_name, prefix='vision/label/', delimiter='/'
)

requests = []

for blob in blobs:
    if search('jpg',blob.name):
        input_image_uri = 'gs://' + bucket_name +'/'+ blob.name
        print(input_image_uri)

        source = {"image_uri": input_image_uri}
        image = {"source": source}
        features = [
            {"type": enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},
        ]

        request = types.AnnotateImageRequest(image=image, features=features)
        requests.append(request)

gcs_destination = {"uri": output_uri}

# The max number of responses to output in each JSON file
batch_size = 2
output_config = {"gcs_destination": gcs_destination,
                 "batch_size": batch_size}

operation = client.async_batch_annotate_images(requests, output_config)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
response = operation.result(90)

# The output is written to GCS with the provided output_uri as prefix
gcs_output_uri = response.output_config.gcs_destination.uri
print("Output written to GCS with prefix: {}".format(gcs_output_uri))
```

However, you can take this as a reference but it would depend on your use-case and code language preference.

Regarding the question about the permissions, I guess you refer to the Cloud Storage bucket ones. Per my understanding it is not necessary to make your images public,  you only have to give read/write [Cloud Storage permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-iam) within the bucket to the service account with which you are executing the requests.

Comment: Thanks, Mariana. I don't have experience with Python yet but will look into it. From the Cloud Shell, how can I download the API response as a JSON?

Comment: You could redirect the response of the executed command to a file, adding "> response.json" at the end of the command, by doing this the response will be stored in the "response.json" file. Please note that you can name the file as you wish.

In order to download the created file you can execute this command within the Cloud Shell "cloudshell download file_name", for further details you can take a look at [Managing files with Cloud Shell documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files).

Comment: Thanks, Mariana.  I'll leave a comment here explaining the above command, in case someone stumbles across this thread.         
In terminal screen: 
1. curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json  https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/
images:annotate?key=your-api-key> response.json
2. cloudshell download response.json

That should download the response file